# Define a date format in a translation string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

In Rails I can format a date with I18n as follows:

```
I18n.l(@order.created_at, format: :long)
```

And I can provide a placeholder in translations:

`config/locales/en.yml:`

```
en:
  order:
    ordered_on_by: "Ordered on %{date} by %{name}
```

Used as:

```
I18n.t('order.ordered_on_by', 
       date: I18n.l(@order.created_at, format: :long),
       name: @order.customer_name)
```

But I'd like to have the date format contained in that `ordered_on_by` translation. So that I can use it as:

```
I18n.t('order.ordered_on_by',
       date: @order.created_at,
       name: @order.customer_name)
```

How can I define a date or time-format in a translation-string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
en:
  order:
    ordered_on_by: "Ordered on %{l date, :fomat => :long} by %{name}
```

if that does not work, you could try to add a `.strftime` to `%{date}` in your en.yml

Comment: Are you sure it works to use the `localize` method inside the locale file?

Comment: Not really, which is why I propose to use. strftime

Comment: The content of `%{}` seems not to get evalled, so it won't help to add `.strfime` or `l()` helpers in there. They appear literally in the output.

Comment: You can actually use ruby code in YAML as you do in a erb view. try `ordered_on_by: "Ordered on <%= l(date, format: :long) %> by %{name}` (but I am not sure that your ERB tag will be aware of the `date` variable...)